# Target iterated fa-icon row in table - Angular , primeNg

Tags: html, angular, html-table, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a nested table made using primeNg. Each row denotes a task. Every row has a `start fa-icon` which starts the task and if a particular task is started, the start button gets replaced by a `stop fa-icon`, incase any user wants to stop the on-going task.

[image]

The task are nested (Note the expand-arrows to the left of rows). With my current code, whenever I click on `start fa-icon`, all the fa-icons in the table gets 'started'. I need to specifycally grab the play fa-icon of the row where the task is initiated and replace that exact play fa-icon with `stop fa-icon`.

I'm replacing start fa-icon with stop fa-icon using `*ngIf` and `Boolean` variables.

**.ts:**

```
  playTask:boolean = true;
  stopTask:boolean = false;

  playClicked(array , i , j, event:any){
   this.playTask = false;
   this.stopTask = true;

   var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
   var idAttr = target.attributes.id
   console.log( "id: ", idAttr);
  }
 
  stopClicked(array , i , j, event:any){
   this.playTask = true;
   this.stopTask = false;
  }
```

**html:**

```
<p-table id="main-table" [value]="tasks" dataKey="col1">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Col 1 <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronUp"></fa-icon><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></th>
                    <th>Col 2 <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronUp"></fa-icon><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></th>
                    <th>Col 3 <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronUp"></fa-icon><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></th>
                    <th>Col 4 <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronUp"></fa-icon><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></th>
                    <th>Col 5 <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronUp"></fa-icon><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></th>
                    <th>Col 6</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body"  let-i="rowIndex" let-parentTasks let-expanded="expanded" >
            <tr *ngFor="let parentTasks of tasks">
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" pButton pRipple [pRowToggler]="parentTasks"  [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-up'"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{parentTasks.row1}}</td>
                    <td>{{parentTasks.row2}}</td>
                    <td>{{parentTasks.row3}}</td>
                    <td>{{parentTasks.row4}}</td>
                    <td>{{parentTasks.row5}}</td>
                    <td>{{parentTasks.row6}}</td>
                <td>
                    <fa-icon *ngIf="playTask" [icon]="faPlayCircle"></fa-icon>
                    <fa-icon *ngIf="stopTask" [icon]="faStopCircle"></fa-icon>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faCommentDots"></fa-icon>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion"  let-parentTasks let-i="rowIndex">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="expandedRow">
                        <p-table [value]="parentTasks.appointments" dataKey="row1">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-childTasks let-j="rowIndex"  let-childTasks.viewDetails="false">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <i (click)="childTasks.viewDetails = !childTasks.viewDetails" [ngClass]="childTasks.viewDetails ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-up'"></i>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{childTasks.row1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{childTasks.row2}}</td>
                                    <td>{{childTasks.row3}}</td>
                                    <td>{{childTasks.row4}}</td>
                                    <td>{{childTasks.row5}}</td>
                                    <td>{{childTasks.row6}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <fa-icon *ngIf="playTask" (click)="playClicked(childTasks, i, j , $event)" id="{{'play'}}" [icon]="faPlayCircle"></fa-icon>
                                        <fa-icon *ngIf="stopTask" (click)="stopClicked(childTasks, i, j, $event)" id="{{'pause'}}" [icon]="faStopCircle"></fa-icon>
                                        <fa-icon [icon]="faCommentDots"></fa-icon>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

I have tried using $event for getting any unique ID of that row but it always returns as empty. Note: View childTasks for the (click) event.

Answer (score 0):

Only the issue with above code I see, you use two way binding for icon attribute. Which is updating your icon global for entire rows of grid.

<fa-icon *ngIf="stopTask" (click)="stopClicked(childTasks, i, j, $event)" id="{{'pause'}}" [icon]="faStopCircle">

#Please try below

<i class="fa fa-stop"  *ngIf="stopTask"   (click)="stopClicked(childTasks, i, j, $event)" >

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. The icons in entire grid gets replaced even with above code.